# Update "sketchy" part of the FAQ

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, faq-contents

The question [Why does this site look so “sketchy”](https://ux.stackexchange.com/faq#sketchy) should be removed from the FAQ now that ux.se has its own design.

Answer (score 2):

That's tricky, because UX is technically not out of beta. Actually not "technically", but *UX is not out of beta, period*.

So it'll have to stay that way because UX is an exception to our process.

Comment: I think the request has more to do with the "sketchy" adjective makes no sense in our context; I initially didn't know what it referred to either in our FAQ. The wording could be better, though the essence of the FAQ (it's beta) should be left

Comment: Not just the word 'Sketchy', but all the imagery used in the FAQ displays the old version of UX.SE.

Comment: The imagery looks the same for all SE sites.